# Typescript annotation error for default React Native app?

Tags: react-native

When creating a fresh React Native project and opening the default app.js file in VSCode, this line;

`const App: () => React$Node = () => {`

returns

`Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.`

as a VSCode problem.

Am I suppose to have typescript installed with React Native, or is this some kind of other issue with VSCode or something? Surely React Native isn't releasing their default app.js file with an error.

Here's the contents of the problem.

```
{
    "resource": "/d:/App/sw_lbi_app/App.js",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "8010",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 27,
    "startColumn": 12,
    "endLineNumber": 27,
    "endColumn": 28
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [Flow](https://flow.org), not TypeScript. Simply remove the types and your code will run without problem.

Comment: Okay done, does react native expect the user's default app.js to support flow?

Comment: Yes as Flow is a tool built by Facebook, which is also behind React Native.

Comment: Okay i'll look into installing it haha. Thank you

Comment: You'll be much better off learning TypeScript, Flow is practically dead nowadays. You don't need to learn any of them if you prefer to stick to JavaScript

Comment: First time I've heard of both. What use does a language like typescript or flow have to react native apps?

Comment: They both offer static type checking which means that you can write safer code and catch errors and typos more easily. Both will prevent you from assigning a `number` to a variable of type `string` or using an undeclared variable (typo), for example. Instead of crashing at runtime when the problematic lines of code are executed, you'll see those at compile time.

Comment: Oh definitely interested to check that out. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212982/discussion-between-yanick-belanger-and-srb633).

Answer (score 7):

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
```

> Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.

In case you want to leave this line of Facebook's code to stay peacefully in Microsoft's VS Code, there is a Setting switch to turn off the TypeScript-style validation in a `.js` file.

Open `Preferences` => `Settings`, search `javascript.validate`, and locate

[image: js validation]

Uncheck it, and re-open `App.js` file. The validation will be gone.

PS: There is an option to make this setting change in User scope or Workspace scope.

Answer (score 1):

It is Flow not TypeScript as mentioned Yanick.

VSC doesn't support it by default, so if you want to keep it the way it is, you can just install
`Flow Language Support` extension in your IDE.